# Scipy Binary Closing - Edge Pixels lose value

Tags: python, image, image-processing, numpy, scipy

I am attempting to fill holes in a binary image.  The image is rather large so I have broken it into chunks for processing.

When I use the `scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_fill_holes` functions, it fills larger holes that belong in the image.  So I tried using `scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_closing`, which gave the desired results of filling small holes in the image.  However, when I put the chunks back together, to create the entire image, I end up with seamlines because the `binary_closing` function removes any values from the border pixels of each chunk.

Is there any way to avoid this effect?

Comment: First, it would be good if you could add an image or some code explaining your problem a bit more. Second, you can't avoid introducing artefacts by slicing in that way, you'll have to pad/expand your slices by the size of your structuring element so that the result will be correct

Comment: The right way to do this is by using morphological reconstruction with the closed image as a marker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operations that involve information from neighboring pixels, such as `closing` will always have trouble at the edges.  In your case, this is very easy to get around: just process subimages that are slightly larger than your tiling, and keep the good parts when stitching together.

Comment: So I just tried something new that I think sounds similar to what you are suggesting.  I took my chunk and added a row of zeros to the top and bottom of the array using vstack.  I did the same to the left and right using hstack.  Then I processed the binary closing.  Finally I removed the outer rows and columns to return the image to its original size.  From what I can tell when I plot the images side by side.  It looks correct.

Comment: That might work, but I think it's less accurate than using actual data from the image.  What I mean is that if your image is say, 1Mx1M, and you want to do this in 100 100Kx100K subimages, process instead subimages that are spaced at the 100K tiling but are 100,200 x 100,200 (ie, have a 100 pixel padding of real and accurate data from the image all the way around), and when you reassemble this just use the good center parts that are 100,000 x 100,000.

Answer (score 6):

Yes.

1. Label your image using `ndimage.label` (first invert the image, holes=black).
2. Find the hole object slices with `ndimage.find_objects`
3. Filter the list of object slices based on your size criteria
4. Invert back your image and perform `binary_fill_holes` on the slices that meet your criteria.

That should do it, without needing to chop the image up. For example:

Input image:

[image]

Output image (Middle size holes are gone):

[image]

Here is the code (inequality is set to remove the middle size blobs):

```
import scipy
from scipy import ndimage
import numpy as np

im = scipy.misc.imread('cheese.png',flatten=1)
invert_im = np.where(im == 0, 1, 0)
label_im, num = ndimage.label(invert_im)
holes = ndimage.find_objects(label_im)
small_holes = [hole for hole in holes if 500 < im[hole].size < 1000]
for hole in small_holes:
    a,b,c,d =  (max(hole[0].start-1,0),
                min(hole[0].stop+1,im.shape[0]-1),
                max(hole[1].start-1,0),
                min(hole[1].stop+1,im.shape[1]-1))
    im[a:b,c:d] = scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_fill_holes(im[a:b,c:d]).astype(int)*255
```

Also note that I had to increase the size of the slices so that the holes would have border all the way around.

Comment: I have trouble spotting any difference between the two images you posted.

Comment: @Jaime - look more closely ;) the medium size holes are absent in the second image.

Comment: My bad! I was looking for teeny weeny holes, the ones gone are much bigger than I was expecting,

Comment: @Jaime - it did occur to me these images may be confusing, but i wanted to illustrate, this approach is a touch more powerful than requested by OP.. hmmm!